# Selenium time outs? How to set time out limit?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm using Selenium Ruby client on a site with really bad performance. My scripts fails each time because of time outs. For a weeks now I am researching how time out limit can be set when using Selenium.

My (Ruby) script is

```
selenium.set_timeout(30000000000000) # does not work?
selenium.open myurl
```

In the Selenium log I can see that setTimeout method is called

```
setTimeout(30000000000000)
open(https://....
```

So it looks like some time out method is called but it doesn't do anything for open. Time out remains default value. Is there some other time out method I should use for open?

Thanks
Onno

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the timeout_in_seconds option when creating your selenium option? This option is used by the open command.

```
def setup
  @verification_errors = []
  @selenium = Selenium::Client::Driver.new \
    :host => "localhost",
    :port => 4444,
    :browser => "*chrome",
    :url => "http://localhost:3000/",
    :timeout_in_seconds => 60

  @selenium.start_new_browser_session
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution above didn't work for me. Then I changed

```
:timeout_in_second => 30
```

to

```
:timeout_in_seconds => 30
```

and everything is fine now:

```
INFO - Command request: setTimeout[30000, ] on session c1e82f8ce2bf45e184f1aa93b4ba3f21
```